# Rails - How to get count of an object in a variable and use in footer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a footer with some statistics like you would see in a forum etc..

I have

**- projects today**

```
SELECT COUNT(project_title) FROM projects;
```

**- projects total**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from projects where date(created_at)=date(date_sub(now(),interval 1 day));
```

**- users joined today**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from users where date(created_at)=date(date_sub(now(),interval 1 day));
```

**- users total**

```
SELECT COUNT(email) FROM users;
```

What i would like to know is how do i actually get the variables to use them in the footer.

The footer file is app/views/layouts/_footer.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the method in

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :total_projects

  def total_projects
    @total_projects = Project.all.size
  end

end
```

app/views/layouts/_footer.html.erb

```
<%= @total_projects %>
```

Comment: You Sir are a gentleman. Thanks you very much. I kind of had the idea of the controller but couldnt figure out what controller to use. So is the understanding that functions in ApplicationController apply to the whole app correct?